# Mouse events through bluetooth

Tags: java, java-me, mouseevent, bluecove

I have to do an assignment in JAVA in which I have to connect to computers through bluetooth device and once they are connected, one computer's mouse can also control other computer's mouse. Means if I want to open my computer on the other computer, I will move the mouse on my computer and select the my computer option on the other computer using my computer's mouse.

What i have done so far is that I have made the connection between two computers successfully. Now i have no idea what to do with mouse. Is there will be some mouse events transfer through bluetooth device or something else?

All the development is done in Java using Bluecove API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) to do the task fastly as it is easier to learn and use. The other alternative is to use JNA or Java Native Access to do the same. 
You can try looking at an [example](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-se-api-tutorials/214-how-control-your-computers-mouse-using-robot-class.html) on using Robot

Answer (score 1):

Would you not get the x and y positions of the mouse and then set the x and y on the other computer?

Mind you, I'm only 13 and have only programmed for one and a bit years. I'm most likely wrong.

Comment: In essence, that's indeed what you want to do. But the question is how to do it, technically?

Comment: I have done that task. I sent the whole mouse events through the ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream classes. And on server sides, i used Robot class to move the mouse on the screen.